# Riemannian distance topological requirements to become a metric

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I was reading the proof of the --well known-- theorem that if $(M, g)$ is a Riemannian manifold, then, one defines the Riemannian distance $d$ on $M$, as
$$  M \times M \ni (a, b) \longmapsto d(a, b) = \inf \left\{ L(c) \bigm| c \textrm{ is a $C^1$ piecewise curve that joins } a, b \right\}$$
where $L(c) = \int_I \sqrt{g(c(t))\cdot(c'(t), c'(t))} \; \textrm d t$. The theorem states that $d$ is indeed a metric compatible with the natural topology of $M$. My question is about the proof found in [1, VII.6] and [2, V.3.1]
at the point where it asserts that " $a \neq b$ implies $d(a,b) > 0$. "

It mentions that 
(*) $a \neq b$ implies that we can find a local chart $(U, \varphi)$ and a closed ball $B$ in $\varphi(U)$ centered at $\varphi(a)$, of radius $r > 0$ such that any curve joining $a$ and $b$ should intersect the sphere $\varphi^{-1}(\partial B)$.

I cannot find any proof to this fact, unless i put the constraint of regularity in the manifold (so it turns to a $T_3$ space). Ok, i can understand that in the case that $M$ is locally compact manifold, or even paracompact, then Hausdorff property is sufficient, but even then, this fact, needs a proof based on the local topological properties of $M$.

My question is: Can we prove (*) without further constraints?

My references to this question are:

[1] S. Lang, "Introduction to Differential manifolds"

[2] W. Boothby, "Introduction to Differential manifolds and Riemannian Geometry"

Comment: I don't have either Lang or Boothby available. Do they really define "Reimannian Manifold" without requiring regularity? Such would be highly unusual. For instance, Wikipedia give the definition "[Formally, a (topological) manifold is a second countable Hausdorff space that is locally homeomorphic to Euclidean space.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Mathematical_definition)".

Comment: Boothby defines manifolds to be locally euclidean, hausdorff and second countable (in the very beginning of his book) so this theorem is consistent to the definition. S. Lang jumps from finite dimensional to infinite dimensional manifolds without major warnings and paracompactness is not always presumed, so it is unclear what assumptions hold every time. But in either case i expected to find some justification of this fact.